# Post to nodejs and return results

Tags: node.js, cross-domain, jsonp, jquery-post

I have been searching for hours on google for away to post from my client js hosted on my site to a nodejs server, than return those results back to my client side.

This is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var my_id = <?=$myuserid;?>;
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mydomain.com:8001/get_friends',
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {
            id: my_id
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(data.error===true){
                alert(data.msg);
            } else {
                alert(data.users);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Than the NodeJS File:

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    sys = require('sys');
var client = mysql.createClient({
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
});

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    client.query('USE mydatabase');
    client.query(
        'SELECT * FROM buddy_list WHERE user_id = "This is where I need my post to go"',
        function selectCb(err, results, fields){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' });
            "Here I need it to feed back results to client script."
            response.end();
            client.end();
    })
}).listen(8001);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input sanitation issues aside, here is how you would solve this:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response){
    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
        dataInput = chunk.toString();
        client.query('USE mydatabase');
        client.query(
            'SELECT * FROM buddy_list WHERE user_id = ' + dataInput,
            function selectCb(err, results, fields){
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' });
                "Here I need it to feed back results to client script."
                response.end();
                client.end();
        })

    })
}).listen(8001);
```

Comment: Is there away to receive those results on the client side server?

Comment: I don't have experience with the mysql connector for nodejs but I would guess that you could replace the `response.end();` line with `response.end({'results': results});`. My advice would be to litter your code with console.log statements to get a better picture of what's going on and when those things occur and what format the data ends up in. However, when you've got data to send back to the client, insert it as the only argument inside of `response.end(argument)`.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't look like I can edit my above comment, but replace `response.end({'results': results});` with `response.end(JSON.stringify({'results': results}));`. My mistake.

Comment: I was able to get it to display the results if I do a straight post to the script, but for some reason doing a ajax post from my client side returns nothing. That's petty much what I have been trying to figure out. Everything else though works great.

Comment: This is assuming that the Chunk is not very large and hence must be done after the first call. What if you have a large Json file? You have to use a `req.on('end', func ... )` to solve the problem and send response at end with `res.end()`

Answer (score 1):

```
response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' });
response.send( JSON.stringify(results) );
```

I have not tried this but it looks like what you want. I'm not sure what results, fields have or if there needs to be more data manipulation. I'm assuming "results" is a JSON object.

Comment: why not just `res.json(results)`

Comment: res.json and res.send are Express native calls and are not recognized in Node core.